# Disable woocommerce api authentication?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The woocommerce api takes oauth1.0 for HTTP requests and basic HTTP authentication for HTTPS requests. My query is simple. How to simply remove this authentication? I did some digging and found there is a class in woocommerce plugin with a constructor as

```
public function __construct() {

        // To disable authentication, hook into this filter at a later priority and return a valid WP_User
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_api_check_authentication', array( $this, 'authenticate' ), 0 );
    }
```

My job is to simply remove the authentication part. Here it is saying to hook this filter at a later priority. How to do so and how to return a valid WP_User?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own plugin and place the following code:

```
function wc_authenticate_alter(){
    //return wp_get_current_user();
    if( 'GET' ==  WC()->api->server->method ){
        return new WP_User( 1 );
    } else {
        throw new Exception( __( 'You dont have permission', 'woocommerce' ), 401 );
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_api_check_authentication', 'wc_authenticate_alter', 1 );
```

This will bypass woocommerce api authentication. Use it with your own risk.

(You can add it in theme's `functions.php` instead of own plugin. But not Tested.)

Comment: add_filter code replaces the add_filter in the _construct right

Comment: It executes after the `add_filter` in `__construct` because of priority 1 as third parameter.

Comment: Does this code also work if I want to remove authentication for a specific custom API endpoint created in a plugin?

Comment: "This is the way" would say a Mandalorian. 
Now consider that doing that everyone is able to see all products details, orders, customers, etc.
This is not recommended to do so on a live site, otherwise in a dev site, it could be done in order to not do any authentication process.

Comment: @Amjad it's only working for WooCommerce, as the filter is "woocommerce_api_check_authentication".