# WooCommerce REST API not authenticating when WordPress user logged in, fine when not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

A bit of a tricky issue.  I'm using the new WooCommerce REST API to list products and make subsequent calls to support custom filters that I'm building.

Authenticating over HTTPS and passing in the consumer secret and consumer key and it works perfectly when there is no WordPress user logged in.

However, if a WordPress user is logged in, it returns a 401 not authorized, even with the same URL that worked when the user was logged out.

I've tried disabling auth as well such as 
[Disable woocomerce api authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623134/disable-woocomerce-api-authentication)
and https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/8106

but it seems those hooks are outdated.

Anyone have any ideas as to why my client is getting bounced only when a WordPress user is logged in?

Comment: So you've got 2 sites and both in WordPress, when the user is logged in on SiteA calling WC API on SiteB doesn't work, but when user is not logged in on SiteA then API calls to SiteB work fine. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Just one site, the front end pulls in content through the API so the user doesn't have to reload the page.

We found that it seemed the user didn't have proper permissions when logged in. So WC was letting the keys through, but when the user was logged in, their permissions weren't great enough. So we were able to override this if the user had supplied the correct credentials.